# Pytorch is deprecated warning, not using GPU

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Since yesterday whenever I try to deploy a new deep learning VM with pytorch i get a warning saying :
The resource 'projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/pytorch-1-1-cu100-20190613' is deprecated. A suggested replacement is 'projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/pytorch-1-1-cu100-20190701'.

And when I try to run my code anyway, it doesn't use the GPU but the CPU. The code is fine, it works on my computer and on google cloud before as well. 
Also did the pricing change? tesla v100 used to be around 350 per month now it's like 1300? Im confused.
It's just annoying to have to work around google cloud and waste money till something works.

I just tried one last time, got the warning again and this time it even said no cuda available GPU, which there was. This is just annoying, I'm working with time, and using this just made me waste money with no results at all so far.

The warning seems to indicate that Pytorch is updated and google needs to get the update? How long would that take? I don't have much time to run my deep learning

Comment: For anyone who encounters this using the DQN tutorial, the slow down was caused by the plot_durations function

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate this when I deployed a Deep Learning VM with Pytorch 1.1 and Tesla v100. Please create an Issue in [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so Google can look into it.

Regarding the pricing, it’s possible you were looking at the pricing for the K80. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#gpus) for GPU pricing details.